# GAMS - logical equations & binary variables

Tags: binary, logical-operators, gams-math

I got another question on logical equations or rather binary variables. This is again a beginner question.

So, right now I'm trying to understand how to set the value of binary variables with conditions.

Consider the binary variable x and variable m.

If I would write the code in other language syntax, what I'm trying to do would look like:

if m > 0
x = True
else
x = False
end

So, I'm trying to set the value of x to 1, when the variable m is greater than zero.

How do I model this in GAMS? Do I need to use logical equations for it?
I can't find a solution for this.

Thanks again for your help.

Cheers
Max

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the following constraints to the model

```
 Eq..    m =g= (x-1)*M
```

where M is a very large positive number representing a lower bound on the variable m.

Comment: I got a similar but more extended solution from another forum. I posted the link below.

Anyhow thank you a lot for taking the time to think about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got a helpful answer from another forum:
https://forum.gamsworld.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10286

This should be the solution to the problem.